# Group Policy Drive Mapping

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

How do I get to the screen which allows me to set drive mappings for Active Directory Group Policy?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Group Policy Management console, edit the GPO you want, then navigate to:

```
User Configuration \ Preferences \ Windows Settings \ Drive Maps
```

Comment: For the sake of people who got here by searching: this applies to Windows Server 2008 and later.

Comment: Specifically, this is using Group Policy Prefences: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx